# Good alternative for using reinterpret_cast

Tags: c++, class, pointers, return, reinterpret-cast

in the below code i dont want to use reinterpret_cast. can anyone  please suggest me with a good solution instead of reinterpret_cast?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<memory>
using namespace std;

//New class which i created
class Commonline
{
 public:
 int Newkey1,Newkey2,Newkey3;
 
 Commonline(){Newkey1=0;Newkey2=0;Newkey3=0; cout<<"Commonline default constructor\n";}

 void Commoninit()
 {
     Newkey1=10;Newkey2=20;Newkey3=30;
 }
 int get_Newkey1()const{return Newkey1;}
 int get_Newkey2()const{return Newkey2;}
 int get_Newkey3()const{return Newkey3;}
 
 ~Commonline(){cout<<"Commonline distructor\n";}
};

//already existing old class
class straightline
{
 public:
 int Oldkey1,Oldkey2,Oldkey3;
 
 straightline(){Oldkey1=0;Oldkey2=0;Oldkey3=0;cout<<"straightline default constructor\n";}

//Here in this old class have created this new constructor for filling new class var values with 
//this old class variables so that to match return type of execute_this().
 straightline(const Commonline *ptr)
 {
    cout<<"straightline parameterised constructor\n";
    Oldkey1 = ptr->get_Newkey1();
    Oldkey2 = ptr->get_Newkey2();
    Oldkey3 = ptr->get_Newkey3();
 }
 void display_strData()
 {
     cout<<"Oldkey1 = "<<Oldkey1<<endl;
     cout<<"Oldkey2 = "<<Oldkey2<<endl;
     cout<<"Oldkey3 = "<<Oldkey3<<endl;
 }
 ~straightline()
 {
     cout<<"straightline distructor\n";
 }

};

//Already existing old function which excpects return type must be straightline*
straightline* execute_this()
{
 //here i wanted to return straightline ptr which holds Commonline object.
 Commonline* Comptr = new Commonline; 
 Comptr->Commoninit();

 straightline *strptr = reinterpret_cast<straightline*>(Comptr);//Please suggest any other good method
 if(strptr == nullptr)
 {
     cout<<"returned null pointer\n";
     return nullptr;
 }
 return strptr;
}

int main()
{
 straightline *strptr = execute_this();
 strptr->display_strData();
}
```

I know using reinterpret_cast here will be a bad idea because in future if any order of member variables changes entire object gets disturbed. just for understanding my problem/requirement i have used it.

NOTE:

I have tried using unique_ptr.reset() in place of reinterpret_cast<> as below

```
  Commonline* Comptr = new Commonline;
  static std::unique_ptr<straightline> strptr;
  strptr.reset(new straightline(Comptr));

  return strptr.get();
```

But after merging the changes it is getting crashed due to in case multiple processes calls execute_this() then reset will delete old ptr it seems.

Comment: `reinterpret_cast` for type punning is UB.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a `straightline` object then you must construct one

```
if (Comptr == nullptr)
{
    cout<<"returned null pointer\n";
    return nullptr;
}
return new straightline(*Comptr);
```

For this to work you need to add a constructor to `straightline` that can make a `straightline` from a `Commonline`.

```
class straightline
{
public:
    int Oldkey1,Oldkey2,Oldkey3;
 
    straightline()
    {
        Oldkey1=0;
        Oldkey2=0;
        Oldkey3=0;
        cout<<"straightline default constructor\n";
    }

    straightline(const Commonline& c)
    {
        Oldkey1=c.get_Newkey1();
        Oldkey2=c.get_Newkey2();
        Oldkey3=c.get_Newkey3();
        cout<<"straightline Commonline constructor\n";
    }

    ...
};
```

Now there are other problems with your code (memory leaks and such) but that's the basic idea to solve the problem you asked about.

Comment: Hi John thanks for your support,
Can you please let me know is it possible to get above functionality without creating dynamic object  (i mean without "new" creating only local object) ?

Because here deleting pointer is big task for me since many where it is used and many backends are accessing it.

Comment: @user16526881 Yes, that will work. The only difference between dynamic objects and local objects is that lifetime of the object, apart from that they work the same. I only used `new` because your code above does as well.

Answer (score 0):

There is really no need for init method. Just implement three argument constructor that does what init do. Then you won't need `execute_this` method.
Though if you'd really want to implement some logic in `execute_this` method, you coud do something like this:

```
template<typename T>
T* execute_this(T* arg) {
//do some logic with arg
return arg;//or whatever you like
}
```

or you can just derive `Commonline` from `straightline` and use its base pointer.

Comment: Thanks John for your kind help, 
Here straightline class is old existing class which fetches values for the variables from diffrent source(src1),

Now i have another source called src2 in which these variables and its values are defined  (Front end migrated from src1 to src2),
Now i need to connect to that src2 and fetch the data from there for all the variables
Commonnit() is doing that part hence i cant remove this method.